# How to remove a parameter name from url with Joomla 4 router

Tags: joomla-4.x, router

My current working url is `example.com/order/?id=abcd&pass=1234`

I want url like `example.com/order/abcd?pass=1234`

After applying below codes in `ROOT/components/com_shop/src/Service/Router.php`

```
public function __construct(SiteApplication $app, AbstractMenu $menu)
{
    $order = new RouterViewConfiguration('order');
    $order->setKey('id');
    $this->registerView($order);

    parent::__construct($app, $menu);

    $this->attachRule(new MenuRules($this));
    $this->attachRule(new StandardRules($this));
    $this->attachRule(new NomenuRules($this));
}

public function getOrderSegment($id, $query)
{
    if (!strpos($id, ':')) {
        $db = Factory::getDbo();
        $dbquery = $db->getQuery(true);
        $dbquery->select($db->quoteName('order_id'))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__orders'))
            ->where($db->quoteName('order_id') . ' = :id')
            ->bind(':id', $id, ParameterType::STRING);
        $db->setQuery($dbquery);

        $id .= ':' . $db->loadResult();
    }

    if ($this->noIDs) {
        list($void, $segment) = explode(':', $id, 2);

        return array($void => $segment);
    }

    return array($id => $id);
}

public function getOrderId($segment, $query)
{
    if ($this->noIDs) {
        $db = Factory::getDbo();
        $dbquery = $db->getQuery(true);
        $dbquery->select($db->quoteName('order_id'))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__orders'))
            ->where($db->quoteName('order_id') . ' = :id')
            ->bind(':id', $segment);
            $db->setQuery($dbquery);

        return $db->loadResult();
    }

    return $segment;
}
```

It returns url like: `example.com/order?pass=1234`, the id is completely gone and also it's showing 404 error.

What should I modify/write in the Router.php to get url like `example.com/order/abcd?pass=1234`?

Note: I did copy above codes from Joomla! core components. I'm still trying to learn Joomla! 4 Router.

Comment: What does non-SEF link to the order look like?

Comment: @Sharky `example.com/index.php?option=com_shop&view=order&id=abcd&pass=1234`

Comment: Where does `order`? Is it the alias of the menu item? Do you have the menu item pointing to a single order? Is there a "list of orders" type of view?

Comment: Yes, `order` is a menu item alias. No list, just a single order details view. But it will show specific order based on the `id` and `pass`.

Comment: What kind of menu item type does `orders` have if you don't have a list view?